# Can't kill a java process listening on port 8080

Tags: java, macos, process, pid, kill

There is a porcess listening in port 8080, i can't kill it, each time it gets a new PID

> lsof -i tcp:8080

```
COMMAND PID  USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    809 user   42u  IPv6 0xd6c1091fd72f0f8f      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
```

> ps -ef 809

```
UID   PID  PPID   C STIME   TTY           TIME CMD
502   809     1   0 12:04   ??         0:09.14 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk- 
12.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java - 
Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/opt/tomcat/libexec/conf/logging.properties - 
Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 - 
Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources - 
Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027 -Dignore.endorsed.dirs= -classpath 
/usr/local/opt/tomcat/libexec/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/opt/tomcat/libexec/bin/tomcat-juli.jar - 
Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/opt/tomcat/libexec -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/opt/tomcat/libexec  - 
Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/opt/tomcat/libexec/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

I tried  **Kill -9 PID** But no way. Please, any suggestion

Comment: There is a process that is restarting the application again whenever it is shutting down. Please look at other processes that might be restarting the java application

Comment: but I don't understand why it's listening on tcp:8080!!

Comment: It's apache server. In the browser you can hopefully connect to the server using http://ip:8080

Comment: It's what Abhishek says. It's probably Apache being run as a service.

Comment: ppid = 1. It's a service. Not Apache, I don't think, but a Java program. Could be tomcat, or any number of things. Search SO for how to stop a macos service.